# Getting data from two tables in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one of tables with Member Ship Names and the other with Monthly Payments for membership.

I want a query to return all member names related to their father name and the last payment for each member from the monthly payment table.

How can I do that ?!

Member Ship table

```
Id | FirstName | fatherName | LastNAme | FullName
```

Monthly Payment

```
Id | FullName | PaymentValue | PaymentDate | MemberShipID
```

Comment: Google `SQL server join`.

Comment: There is really too much questions like this asked on SO, just search and do a little of effort, if you couldn't solve your problem then come with what you've tried and ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `outer apply`:

```
select *
from memberships m
outer apply(select top 1 * from payments 
            where membershipid = m.id order by paymentdate desc)oa
```